# Cannot call `JSON.parse` with `localStorage.getItem(...)`

Tags: javascript, json

Just added Flow types to a project I'm working on and progressively adding types until I got to this error:

> Cannot call JSON.parse with localStorage.getItem(...) bound to text because null or undefined [1] is incompatible with
>   string [2]

This comes from a expression:

```
const myVar = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemName'))
```

I understand why I get this error (except maybe the ***"bound to text"*** part), but couldn't find a way around it. I'd appreciate any help here!

Comment: because `localStorage.getItem("someItem")` can return a null value as well

Comment: Yes, this is the part I understand. The next step should be something like setting JSON.parse to accept null or undefined maybe? And how?

Comment: you can do an if statement or something like: `localStorage.getItem("someItem") || {}`

Comment: I tried something similar and unfortunately doesn't help. It just adds  `object literal is incompatible with string` to the error. Problem is that `JSON.parse` only accepts a string. I guess I could wrap the getItem to a function and make sure it always returns a string but there should be a better solution.

Comment: `localStorage.getItem("someItem") || '{}'` wrap the object in string

Comment: This takes the error away same as the wrapper function I mentioned before, thanks @DakshMiglani.

Comment: let me put this as an answer for future references.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, the function `localStorage.getItem` can return `null` values and flow wants you to tackle them before parsing it. As `JSON.parse` only takes a string, you can do the following:

`localStorage.getItem("key") || '{}'`

So, if it returns null. The empty object string is chosen, which `JSON.parse` can parse into an empty object.

Answer (score 1):

Prefer using 'null' than '{}' as it parses to empty object

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("key") || 'null') // null

JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("key") || '{}') // {} - empty object
```