# JSON.parse an Undefined object from Local Storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am having a LocalStorage item which I am parsing into a variable like this:

```
let resp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('someKey'));
```

The thing is sometimes, the localStorage may not have the value and it may return an Undefined object to parse which is resulting in following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0
```

I have tried this:

```
let resp = localStorage.getItem('someKey') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('someKey')) : null;
```

But I believe this is not very optimal way of handling this, any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46613243/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-u-in-json-at-position-0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot call \`JSON.parse\` with \`localStorage.getItem(...)\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52718844/cannot-call-json-parse-with-localstorage-getitem)

Answer (score 1):

your solution is just fine, if you want it to be shorter, you could try this

```
let resp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('someKey') || null)
```

Here is how it works:

1. `localStorage.getItem('someKey') || null` will evaluate the left side of the code first, if `localStorage.getItem('someKey')` returns `undefined` or `''` empty string, it will return the right side code which is `null`
2. Then, `JSON.parse(null)` will return `null` instead of error

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
let resp = null;
const storedResp = localStorage.getItem('someKey');
if (storedResp) {
  try {
    resp = JSON.parse(storedResp);
  } catch (e) {}
}
```

This shouldn't generate any errors since you're only parsing it to JSON if it exists, and then catching any errors if JSON parsing fails. You're left with `resp` being equal to `null` or the stored data as JSON, with no errors in any case.

As others have said, your current solution is fine, but there are two potential issues with it as written:

- You access the item in `localStorage` twice, which may be unnecessarily slow if it is a large object.
- Many companies prefer (or require) that you wrap lines at 80 characters and your current solution is 96 characters long.